# Proving that $\lfloor{X} \rfloor$ is a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, measurable-functions

> Let $X \sim$ Exp$(\lambda)$ and $Y:=\lfloor{X} \rfloor$.
>
> How to prove that $Y$ is a random variable?

I used:

I want to show that $Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

Since $X \sim$ Exp$(\lambda)$, the cumulative distribution function is $F_X(x)=1-e^{-ay}$

I know that floor functions are monotone piecewise continuous functions.

So I wrote the floor function as

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n \, \chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)$$

But how can I conclude that $Y$ is a random variable?

Comment: Rewriting the floor function is a good move. The set $[n, n+1)$ is measurable, so its characteristic function $\chi_{[n, n+1)}(x)$ is a measurable simple function. Sums of simple functions are measurable, and pointwise limits of real-valued measurable functions are measurable. Can you conclude?

Comment: @snar: isn't it about the measurability of $Y$ and not about the measurability of the floor function.

Comment: Alternatively, $\{\omega : Y(\omega) = k\} = \{ \omega : k \leq X(\omega) < k+1\} = X^{-1}([k, k+1)).$

Comment: @user251257 $Y(\omega) = (h\circ X)(\omega)$, where $h$ is the floor function, so $Y$ is $\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{B}$-measurable if $h$ is $\mathscr{B}/\mathscr{B}$-measurable and $X$ is $\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{B}$-measurable (given since $X$ is an RV), ie using the composition lemma for measurable functions

Comment: Recall that $\mathbb P(X\geqslant 0)=1$ so your sum should be from $n=0$ to $\infty$.